# Why do Matlab's imread and OpenCV's imread return different pixel values when reading the same image?

Tags: python, image, matlab, opencv, imread

The image in question is a uint16 pgm image with a bit depth of 10 but saved as 16-bit. When reading the image using Matlab's imread, the pixel values are 2^6 times larger than those obtained using OpenCV's imread with the parameter cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED. Both functions return a uint16 data type.

```
I_tmp = imread(imageFileName)
```

[matlab pixel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvxve.png)

```
image = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

[opencv pixel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyHOv.png)
I want to know why this situation occurs and how I can read the same pixel values in Python as in Matlab.

Comment: could you provide the matlab and opencv code you are using to read the image?

Comment: ye,I have added to the question

Comment: What data type is `image` in your OpenCV case?

Comment: OpenCV should be producing a 16-bit array there. But you can also try using the `imageio` package to read images in Python.

Comment: In opencv case, it returns a unit16 ndarray

Comment: @Cris Luengo
thx for your advice, i got same pixel value by imageio, but why, it puzzled me, maybe i need to check their API documentation in more detail